# Spark Column level Data based on data type in a pyspark data frame

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, sqldatatypes

I am trying get Column level Data based on data type of column name

If column data type is

- string - get count, distinct count values
- int/decimal - get min, max, mean, count, distinct count values
- date/datetime - get min, max, count, distinct count

and keep in a metrics_df like

```
column_name,data_type,type,value,
id,int,min,1
id,int,max,5
id,int,mean,2.5
id,int,avg,2.5
id,int,discount,5
id,int,count,5

name,string,name,5

join_date,date,min,2023-01-01
join_date,date,max,2023-01-05
date,date,discount,5
date,date,count,5
```

I am trying below code

```
import pyspark 
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, to_date, max, min, mean, avg, greatest, lit, countDistinct
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, StringType, LongType,TimestampType, DateType

###Defined a Sample Dataframe
myManualSchema = StructType([
  StructField("id", LongType(), True),
  StructField("emp_name", StringType(), True),
  StructField("Salary", LongType(), True),
  StructField("join_date", StringType(), True)
])
myRow1 = Row(1, "Siva1",100, "2023-01-01")
myRow2 = Row(2, "Siva2",200, "2023-01-02")
myRow3 = Row(2, "Siva2",300, "2023-01-02")
myRow4 = Row(4, "Siva4",400, "2023-01-04")
myRow5 = Row(5, "Siva5",500, "2023-01-05")
myDf = spark.createDataFrame([myRow1,myRow2,myRow3,myRow4,myRow5],myManualSchema)
df = myDf.withColumn('join_date',to_date(col('join_date'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))


###Actual Logic starts from here
    emp_RDD = spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD()
    schema = StructType([
      StructField('Column_name', StringType(), True),
      StructField('Data_type', StringType(), True),
      StructField('Type', StringType(), True),  
      StructField('Value', StringType(), True)
      ])
    
    finaldf = spark.createDataFrame(data=emp_RDD,schema=schema)
    final = []
for c,t in df.dtypes:
    #Change/Add your datatypes here for numeric
    if(t in ["bigint","long"]):
        for metric in ["MIN","MAX","AVG","MEAN"]:
            lst=[]
            lst.append(c)
            lst.append(t)
            lst.append(metric)     
            expr=metric.lower()+"("+c+")"
            value=df.selectExpr(expr).first()[0]
            lst.append(value)
            final.append(lst)
```

But unable to adjust code for all datatypes, Can any suggest any other method or logic to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a mapping between data type and the metrics you want to calculate. Since you're using `df.selectExpr(expr)`, you'll also want your expression to be compatible with SQL – the SQL expression for `CountDistinct` would be `COUNT(DISTINCT({col_name}))`.

```
###Actual Logic starts from here
emp_RDD = spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD()
schema = StructType([
  StructField('Column_name', StringType(), True),
  StructField('Data_type', StringType(), True),
  StructField('Type', StringType(), True),  
  StructField('Value', StringType(), True)
  ])

finaldf = spark.createDataFrame(data=emp_RDD,schema=schema)
final = []

## this can be expanded as needed
type_metric_map = {
    'bigint': ["MIN","MAX","AVG","MEAN","COUNT", "COUNTDISTINCT"],
    'string': ["COUNT", "COUNTDISTINCT"],
    'date': ["MIN","MAX","COUNT", "COUNTDISTINCT"]
}

for c,t in df.dtypes:
    #Change/Add your datatypes here for numeric
    if t in type_metric_map:
        for metric in type_metric_map[t]:
            lst=[]
            lst.append(c)
            lst.append(t)
            lst.append(metric)
            if metric == "COUNTDISTINCT":
                expr=f"count(distinct ({c}))"
            else:
                expr=metric.lower()+"("+c+")"
            value=df.selectExpr(expr).first()[0]
            lst.append(value)
            final.append(lst)
```

This is what `final` looks like:

```
[['id', 'bigint', 'MIN', 1],
 ['id', 'bigint', 'MAX', 5],
 ['id', 'bigint', 'AVG', 2.8],
 ['id', 'bigint', 'MEAN', 2.8],
 ['id', 'bigint', 'COUNT', 5],
 ['id', 'bigint', 'COUNTDISTINCT', 4],
 ['emp_name', 'string', 'COUNT', 5],
 ['emp_name', 'string', 'COUNTDISTINCT', 4],
 ['Salary', 'bigint', 'MIN', 100],
 ['Salary', 'bigint', 'MAX', 500],
 ['Salary', 'bigint', 'AVG', 300.0],
 ['Salary', 'bigint', 'MEAN', 300.0],
 ['Salary', 'bigint', 'COUNT', 5],
 ['Salary', 'bigint', 'COUNTDISTINCT', 5],
 ['join_date', 'date', 'MIN', datetime.date(2023, 1, 1)],
 ['join_date', 'date', 'MAX', datetime.date(2023, 1, 5)],
 ['join_date', 'date', 'COUNT', 5],
 ['join_date', 'date', 'COUNTDISTINCT', 4]]
```

Comment: I am getting java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Etc/UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=?,YEAR=2017,MONTH=1,WEEK_OF_YEAR=?,WEEK_OF_MONTH=?,DAY_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_YEAR=?,DAY_OF_WEEK=?,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=?,AM_PM=1,HOUR=3,HOUR_OF_DAY=15,MINUTE=19,SECOND=30,MILLISECOND=85,ZONE_OFFSET=?,DST_OFFSET=?]' kind of data in date , timestamp fields. any help?